# How to check Session and Validate the request in .Net Core Web API

Tags: .net, asp.net-core-webapi

I am creating a .Net Core web API V3 project and in that project, I have a requirement:

On every request check the SESSION, if it is ACTIVE then proceed else STOP the request and throw BAD REQUEST error.

Now In my application, I have a SESSION table in my database and in that table I have a few columns among which I have

Active (bit),

Last Activity (Datetime(2)),

Ended (Datetime(2)) column

What I need:

1- I need to update LastActivity column on every REQUEST on API.

2- And in that context, we should validate that we have already set the session timeout value to 2 minutes in appSettings.json so then on every request we should first validate that if the time from LastActivity and current DateTime minutes is not greater then 2 minutes, if it is, then throws BadRequest error and stop the execution, else let it go and update the LastActivity column to current DateTime.

What I Have Already Done (And is not working)

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using DataAccess.Dtos;
using DataAccess.Models;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Filters;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Service.Contracts;

namespace Motorlogs.API.Shared
{
    public class SessionActionFilter : IActionFilter
    {
        public void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
        {
            ISessionService _ISessionService = null;
            IConfiguration _IConfiguration = null;

            if (LoggedInUser.SessionId != null)
            {
                Session session = _ISessionService.GetSessions(x => x.SID == LoggedInUser.SessionId).FirstOrDefault();

                if (session != null)
                {
                    if (session.Active == false)
                    {
                        context.Result = new BadRequestObjectResult("Session Expired! Please login again.");
                        return;
                    }

                    if (!session.LastActivity.HasValue)
                    {
                        session.LastActivity = DateTime.Now;
                        _ISessionService.UpdateSession(session);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        var lastActivityTime = session.LastActivity;
                        var currentTime = DateTime.Now;
                        var requestDuration = currentTime.Subtract((DateTime)lastActivityTime);
                        var sessionTimeOutMinutes = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(int.Parse(_IConfiguration.GetSection("AppSettings:SessionExpiryTime").Value)).Minutes;

                        if (requestDuration.Minutes >= sessionTimeOutMinutes)
                        {
                            session.Ended = DateTime.Now;
                            session.Active = false;
                            _ISessionService.UpdateSession(session);
                            context.Result = new BadRequestObjectResult("Session Expired! Please login again.");
                            return;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            session.LastActivity = DateTime.Now;
                            _ISessionService.UpdateSession(session);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        public void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext context)
        {
            // our code after action executes
        }
    }
}
```

And in Startup.cs

```
        public IServiceProvider ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {

            services.AddDbContext<MotorlogsContext>(x =>
                x.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));

            services.AddMvc(option => option.EnableEndpointRouting = false)
                //.AddNewtonsoftJson(options =>
                //    options.SerializerSettings.PreserveReferencesHandling = PreserveReferencesHandling.Objects)
                .AddNewtonsoftJson(options =>
                    options.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore);

            services.AddCors(c =>
            {
                c.AddPolicy("AllowOrigin", options => options.AllowAnyOrigin().AllowAnyMethod().AllowAnyHeader());
            });

            services.AddAuthentication(options =>
                {
                    options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                    options.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                })
                .AddJwtBearer(options =>
                {
                    options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                    {
                        ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                        IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(
                            Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(
                                Configuration.GetSection("AppSettings:Token").Value)),
                        ValidateIssuer = false,
                        ValidateAudience = false
                    };
                });

            services.AddDistributedMemoryCache();

            services.AddSession(options =>
            {
                options.IdleTimeout =
                    TimeSpan.FromMinutes(int.Parse(Configuration.GetSection("AppSettings:SessionExpiryTime")
                        .Value));
            });

            var identitySettingsSection = Configuration.GetSection("EmailConfiguration");
            services.Configure<EmailConfiguration>(identitySettingsSection);
            services.AddAutoMapper(typeof(Startup));

            services.AddSignalR(hubOptions =>
            {
                hubOptions.EnableDetailedErrors = true;
                hubOptions.KeepAliveInterval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1);
            });

            services.AddHttpContextAccessor();

            services.AddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();
            services.AddSignalR();
            services.AddHostedService<NotificationsHostedService>();

            // This is the line I added for my SessionActionFilter
            services.AddScoped<SessionActionFilter>();

            return ConfigureIoC(services);
        }
```

Article I referred:

https://code-maze.com/action-filters-aspnetcore/

Thanks.

Comment: What's the problem now?

Comment: My created Action Filter is not hitting.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to add a filter globally for all controllers, actions, you should configure it like below:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddMvc(options =>
    {
        options.Filters.Add(typeof(SessionActionFilter));
    });
}
```

For more details, refer to the document of [filters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/filters?view=aspnetcore-3.1#filter-scopes-and-order-of-execution).